# Prevent input blur upon mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text input, and a hidden list. The list will show and hide upon focusing and blurring the input. However, I want the list remain showing when I click on the list (outside the input), i.e., only hide the list when click on outside of it. How to achieve that?

==== html ====

```
<input type="text" id="regioninput">
<ol class="continentlist">
  //php code to generate list items
</ol>
```

==== js ====

```
$('#regioninput').bind('focus', function() {
    $('.continentlist').show();
});
$('#regioninput').bind('blur', function() {
    $('.continentlist').hide();
});
$('.continentlist li').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
    ...
});
```

Comment: I believe you can check to see if the list has focus:  `if($('.continentlist').is(':focus')`, but I am not sure if this works for non-form elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your code a bit so instead of using `blur` and `focus` you can just use `click` on different elements:

```
//show the list when you click the input
$('#regioninput').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.continentlist').show();
});

//hide the list when the document receives a click
$(document).bind('click', function () {
    $('.continentlist').hide();
});

//make sure that if the user clicks on the list they won't hide it
$('.continentlist').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qUeXS/

`event.stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling up the DOM: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation

On a side-note, this works because of event bubbling. No matter where you click on a document, the `document` object will receive that click event after it bubbles all the way up the DOM. So if we cancel the bubbling of the event we can stop the `document` object from receiving the event.